# Saving hive queries

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql, bigdata

I need to know how we can store a query I have written in a command line just like we do in sql(we use ctrl+S in sql server).

I heared hive QL queries use .q or .hql extension.Is there any possibility I save my query to get the same by saving list of commands I am executing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

sure whatever ide you use you can just save your file as myfile.q and then run it from the command line as

```
hive -f myfile.q
```

You can also do

```
hive -f myfile.q > myfileResults.log
```

if you want to pipe your results into a log file.

Answer (score 1):

Create a new file using "cat" command(You can even use editor).Write all the queries you want to perform inside the file

```
$cat > MyQueries.hql
query1
query2
.
.
Ctrl+D
```

Note: .hql or .q is not necessary. It is just for our reference to identify that it is a hive query(file).

You can execute all the queries inside the file at a time using

```
$hive -f MyQueries.hql
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use hue or web interface to access hive instead of terminal. It will provide you UI from where you can write and execute queries. Solves copy problem too.

http://gethue.com/

https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/HiveWebInterface